# Multiple ifel statements to eliminate bad quality pixels from a SpatRaster

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, raster, terra

I am using NASA's Black Marble monthly nighttime light (NTL) product, [VNP46A3](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/missions-and-measurements/products/VNP46A3/). The data are in `.h5` format and apart from the radiance product, they come with quality assurance (QA) data. I am using the All_Angle_Composite_Snow_Free radiance NTL image for my analysis. Using the below code I extracted the radiance image as well as the QA rasters:

```
library(terra)

wd <- "path/"

s <- sds(paste0(wd, "VNP46A3.A2018182.h06v05.001.2021125183820.h5"))

# extract single image as spatraster from h5
r <- s[5] # s[] are the radiance and QA rasters

writeRaster(r, paste0(wd, "NTL.tif"))
```

The next step is the preprocessing of the NTL images, i.e., to eliminate bad quality pixels. I am using the `ifel` function from the `terra` package in `R` to achieve this. There are 2 QA rasters:

- Quality is a binary raster and the good quality pixels have the value of 0
- Num is the number of observations being used to create the monthly raster and should have a value greater than 0

I want to create `ifel` statement(s) such as:

*if the Quality = 0 and Num > 0 then keep the NTL raster values else set the NTL raster values to NULL*.

I have tried to create 2 separate `ifel` statements and then combine the results but I am getting an error:

```
NTL <- rast(paste0(wd, "NTL.tif"))
Num <- rast(paste0(wd, "Num.tif"))
Quality <- rast(paste0(wd, "Quality.tif"))

r <- ifel(Quality = 0, NTL, NULL)
# Error in .local(test, ...) : argument "no" is missing, with no default

r1 <- ifel(Num > 0, NTL, NULL)
# Error in .local(test, ...) : argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Do you perhaps want NA rather than NULL?

Comment: I've tried replacing `NULL` with `NA` but I get the same error.

Comment: What do you mean by no luck? Surely you don't get the same error?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the comment. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try explicitly naming the arguments? For example `ifel(Quality == 0, yes = NTL, no = NA_real_)`

Comment: Also, note it should be `Quality == 0`, not `Quality = 0`

Comment: I think it worked and also I managed to combine both conditions: `r <- ifel(Quality ==0 & Num > 0, yes = NTL, no = NA_real_)`. I wasn't aware of the `NA_real_`.